# StyleCop - auto sorting type members

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, stylecop

is there any plugin for Resharper or VS extensions for auto sorting class/struct members as suggested by StyleCop?  I.e. something which sorts public, protected, then private properties, then public, protected, private methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at StyleCop for ReSharper? http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com

Comment: Hi Hadi, yes we are using that, but does it have an auto sort members option?  I haven't seen one...

Comment: I'm not a StyleCop guy so not really sure, but if it doesn't do it, can't you use the Layout Patterns from ReSharper to sort accordingly?

Comment: Resharper has a re-order type members option in the code clean-up feature.   Code is ordered according to rules in the Type Member Layout XML.   The "StyleCop For Resharper" plugin _now_ comes with a settings file that you can import which will match style cop's requirements exactly.